# What do I need to do additionally to set up libhdfs (for c++)?

Tags: java, c++, hadoop

I'm new to hadoop and I got hadoop installed. Datanode, Namenode etc. are coming up, everything is smooth. Do i have to download libhdfs separately or it comes in the package ? All I can see is Java stuff for it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/LibHdfs.html (though some of the information, notoriously how to make the example, is outdated)

In order to compile it, you'll need to include the $HADOOP_HOME/include directory and to link to $HADOOP_HOME/lib/native/libhdfs.so (if you are on Linux). Also, you'll need to make sure that when you run your example, the CLASSPATH includes all hadoop libraries. One of the tricks to do it:

```
for file in `hadoop classpath | tr ':' ' ' | sort | uniq`
do
  export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
done
```

Caveats:

0) the latest linux distro for Hadoop (2.4.1) includes 32-bit shared libraries, which makes 64-bit systems complain. In order to make this example running on 64bit system, you have to provide native libhdfs.so library. That can be done, for example, by downloading Hadoop from source and build a distibution yourself (a useful intro can be found here: http://csrdu.org/nauman/2014/01/23/geting-started-with-hadoop-2-2-0-building/).

1) on Ubuntu, you'll have to instantiate jvm yourself (via JNI) prior to calling libhdfs, because the libhdfs code mistakenly identifies YamVM for the running JVM, therefore does not instantiate

2) on RedHat, I saw this example hanging if the hdfs was not used after datanode and namenode were restarted.

Comment: Hey, do you have any idea on this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833273/not-seeing-file-on-hdfs-after-writing-using-libhdfs-c-api